# good to cache a lot of variables?

Tags: php, caching

We have an Android App with large number of users (about 300K) with lot of requests and calculations using a PHP web-service.

we have a function named getUserRank that takes user_id & timePeriod to calculate the user rank according to 3 tables (using huge joins) and we use it in our app a lot for every single user.

```
/*
 * get user rank of the user according to the specified period
 * periods: 0-> all  1-> daily  2-> weekly 3-> monthly
 */
public function getUserRank($user_id, $timePeriod){
// piece of code
}
```

I use Xcache and mod_php on my server. Is this a good job to store all of the user ranks for few hours before requesting from database in such a way (to send them by json to the App)?

```
$rank = xcache_get($user_id.$timePeriod); // generate cache id using $user_id.$timePeriod
if($rank == null){
// calculate and populate the cache variable
}
```

Comment: If the rank is usually static for some time then it sounds like it would make sense to cache it. I would create a generic cache class/methods though so you don't get xcache spesific code everywhere but instead do cache_set / cache_get / cache_flush (have to do this when a rank changes). That way you can easily change to another cache service (ie memcached) later

Comment: It is just an example. In fact I use Yii functions to do that. thank you